# How to properly check the available path on a maze

Tags: c#, algorithm, console-application, maze

I am learning c# and programming. I have this task to find a path out of a maze.

I have a 2D matrix where:

- 5 - is the end point.
- 3 - is my start point.
- 2 - is the walkable path.
- 1 - is the wall.

I wrote this code:

```
public static bool PathFinder(MapFile map)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < map.width; x++)
            {
                if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 3)
                {
                    map.Matrix[x, y] = 11;
                    map.start = true;
                    return map.end;
                }
                if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 2)
                {
                    map.Matrix[x, y] = 9;
                    return map.end;
                }
                if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 1)
                {
                    return map.end;
                }
                if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 5)
                {
                    map.Matrix[x, y] = 11;
                    map.end = true;
                    return map.end;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I did not understand how to check if a point on my matrix is a valid path and then walk to the next point.

What should I consider and which direction could I look to try find a solution?

OBS.:

map.start is a boolean that returns true if the start point of the maze was found.

map.end is a boolean that returns true if the end of the maze was found.

The values 9 and 11 are just references I am using to change the color of that point on the console.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm ?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with two loops. You need to implement [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).